# Create a special layer in CNN with keras

Tags: deep-learning

I have a CNN with architecture as follow:
[click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysKjP.png)
where there exists a layer with its input equal to sum of output of 16 layers before it (see Figure). How can I create this layer?

Comment: which framework are you looking for, e.g. Caffe, Keras, Theano etc.

Comment: Keras, as mentioned in title above

Comment: I don't know why I asked that question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine this the part of the architecture that you want to implement:

```
| RELU |  -- > | RELU |  --> |  RELU | -->  | RELU |
    |              |              |             |        
    |              |              |             |     
    ----------------> | RELU | <-----------------
```

Let's assume you have a (32, 32) tensor coming  from some previous layer. 
And that you are using the functional API.

```
# no non-linearity in the Dense layers 
# so you  can apply it in the next node in the graph.
d1 = Dense(32, 32, activation='linear'))(previous-layer)
r1 = LeakyReLU((32,)))(d1)
d2 = Dense(32, 32, activation='linear'))(r1)
r2 = LeakyReLU((32,)))(d2)
d3 = Dense(32, 32, activation='linear'))(r2)
r3 = LeakyReLU((32,)))(d3)
d4 = Dense(32, 32, activation='linear'))(r3)
r4 = LeakyReLU((32,)))(r4)
```

Assuming your really want to add the Tensors then [`keras.layers.add()`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#add) would do

```
adder = add([r1, r2, r3, r4])
d5 = Dense((32, 32), activation="linear")(adder)
r5 = SReLu((32,))(d5)
```

If instead your want concatenate the layers along the columns use 
[`keras.layers.concatenate()`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate)

```
concat = concatenate([r1, r2, r3, r4])
d5 = Dense((32, 32), activation="linear")(concat)
r5 = SReLu((32,))(d5)
```

Nothing's wrong with trying both and seeing which works better for your problem.